# Ruby `.in?` mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new to ruby, I saw a line `if !'Region' .in? region`. What does `.in?` mean? I tried searching for this in all the blogs but could not find any. Please share the relavant documentations if any.

Comment: https://apidock.com/rails/v6.1.3.1/Object/in%3F

Comment: It just checks if a string is in an object, the bang infront means check that its not in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo.in?(bar)` calls the method named `in?` on the object referenced by `foo` and passes the result of evaluating the expression `bar` as an argument.

As with all object-oriented languages, the object the method is called on decides what the method means. So, if you want to know what `in?` means, you have to look at what kind of object `foo` is, then check where the definition of `in?` is coming from for that object, and then read the documentation of that method.

You tagged your question with [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby), but there is no `in?` method defined for [`String`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/String.html)s in Ruby. Therefore, the method must come from somewhere else, maybe some third-party library.

You also tagged your question with [ruby-on-rails-3](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3). Ruby on Rails includes the [`activesupport`](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport) RubyGem which adds a number of [*Core Extensions*](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html) to the Ruby core libraries. One of these core extensions is [testing for *inclusion*](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#in-questionmark):

> ## 2.14 `in?`
>
> The predicate `in?` tests if an object is included in another object. An `ArgumentError` exception will be raised if the argument passed does not respond to `include?`.
>
> Examples of `in?`:
>
> ```ruby
> 1.in?([1,2])        # => true
> "lo".in?("hello")   # => true
> 25.in?(30..50)      # => false
> 1.in?(1)            # => ArgumentError
> ```

[Here is the documentation which is part of Ruby on Rails 3.2.16](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.16/):

> ## `in?(*args)`
>
> Returns true if this object is included in the argument(s). Argument must be any object which responds to `#include?` or optionally, multiple arguments can be passed in. Usage:
>
> ```ruby
> characters = ["Konata", "Kagami", "Tsukasa"]
> "Konata".in?(characters) # => true
>
> character = "Konata"
> character.in?("Konata", "Kagami", "Tsukasa") # => true
> ```
>
> This will throw an `ArgumentError` if a single argument is passed in and it doesn't respond to `#include?`.

And [this is how it is implemented](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ebf69ab1636df74c76332c53bcd3d8494fb91b45/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/inclusion.rb#L13-L24):

> ```ruby
> def in?(*args)
>   if args.length > 1
>     args.include? self
>   else
>     another_object = args.first
>     if another_object.respond_to? :include?
>       another_object.include? self
>     else
>       raise ArgumentError.new("The single parameter passed to #in? must respond to #include?")
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```

As you can see,

```ruby
'Region'.in?(region)
```

simply delegates to

```ruby
region.include?('Region')
```

In modern versions of Ruby on Rails, [it still exists](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-in-3F):

> ## `in?(another_object)`
>
> Returns true if this object is included in the argument. Argument must be any object which responds to `#include?`. Usage:
>
> ```ruby
> characters = ["Konata", "Kagami", "Tsukasa"]
> "Konata".in?(characters) # => true
> ```
>
> This will throw an `ArgumentError` if the argument doesn't respond to `#include?`.

As you can see, the behavior has slightly changed: the support for multiple arguments has been removed. Consequently, [the implementation is now simply](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7c70791470fc517deb7c640bead9f1b47efb5539/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/inclusion.rb#L12-L16):

> ```ruby
> def in?(another_object)
>   another_object.include?(self)
> rescue NoMethodError
>   raise ArgumentError.new("The parameter passed to #in? must respond to #include?")
> end
> ```

You can easily find most of this out yourself by just asking Ruby:

```ruby
# Grab the method:
meth = 'Region'.method(:in?)

# Ask the method who its owner is:
meth.owner
#=> Object

# Ask the method where it is defined:
meth.source_location
#=> ['lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/inclusion.rb', 12]
```

Please note that Ruby on Rails 3 is massively out of date. It has not been maintained in many years, it does not work with current Ruby versions, and it has unpatched security vulnerabilities. You should *strongly* consider updating to a supported and maintained version of Ruby on Rails.